# Can't Read Header values from Javax REST API

Tags: java, web-services, rest

Hi I have a problem with read HTTP header parameters from javax rest API. This is how I implemented the REST API and READ the Header.

```
 @GET
    @Path(value = "/jwt")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Response testJwtLogin(@HeaderParam("token") String token){
return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(responseDetails).build();};
```

I have added header parameter using Postman rest client. So It always gives the 404 RESPONSE code. It means javax server identify header parameter as actual parameter. And I want to know is there any configuration needed to be done. I also try with the http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/get-http-header-in-jax-rs/ these two implementations.Both two give the same output.

Comment: Did you try testing it using **Rest client App** of Chrome?

Comment: Also, can you share some more code ?

Comment: Hi Depika ,Using wireshark i have check the header.So my parameter was in the header.No problem with that.

Comment: Hi @peeskillet i have check the header.So it is in the request.My problem is REST API is not mapping the request.

Comment: Why would the absence of the header result in a 404? Is that the way you have programmed it?

Comment: i just want to read the header parameter.But it always gives 404 error.

Comment: Then it is probably not a problem with the header. It something else you are not showing us. Are you saying that if you don't use the header you don't get a 404? My question is that why do you think the header has anything to do with why you are getting the 404

Answer (score 0):

I think i have solve my problem using this way.

```
@Context  private HttpHeaders headers;
 @GET
    @Path(value = "/jwt")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Response testJwtLogin(){
String parameter = headers.getRequestHeader("parameter").get(0);
return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(responseDetails).build();};
```